# Le mot « trombone » pour l'agrafe est-il un emploi « propre au français de France » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, québec, france, belgique

Le mot [*trombone*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trombone) pour la *petite agrafe repliée en deux boucles* semblerait un emploi « propre au français de France (en Belgique on dit *attache-tout*) » (DHLF/Rey).

Qu'en est-il ?

Comment: Évidemment, on entend ici "propre au français de France" relativement au français de Belgique. Selon l'article [*attache-tout*](https://www.bdlp.org/fiche/5548) de la BDLP-Belgique, "*Trombone* est également en usage en Belgique francophone." Il faudrait voir si, subjectivement, il y a des Belges qui perçoivent quand même *trombone* comme étant un usage typiquement étranger. Le même article précise qu'on dit aussi souvent *attache trombone*.

Comment: Oui, je l'ai entendu des deux façons, une ou un. Et penses-tu qu'on entende plus "attache", "agrafe" ou "trombone"? *Attache*, c'est plus général. Ça inclut d'autres types d'attaches, mais on choisit le terme général au lieu du terme particulier. Pour "propre au français de France" en fait, ce que je veux dire, c'est que ce genre d'affirmation est très souvent relative. On peut dire que certains emplois sont caractéristiques du Québec, même s'ils sont partagés avec, par exemple, l'Acadie. C'est que, de manière implicite, il y a un point de comparaison, qui est souvent la France.

Comment: Ici on utilise la Belgique comme point de comparaison pour la France. Mais je me trompe peut-être. Peut-être que Rey pensait vraiment que "trombone" ne se disait qu'en France. Mais dans ce cas, je ne vois pas comment il pourrait avancer comme seule justification le fait qu'on utilise un autre mot en Belgique.

Comment: @Anonymous Ah ok, là je comprends, pas de déduction avec seulement le truc sur la Belgique ; relatif ; la norme. _Trombone_ est très français finalement. Bien, oui c'est ça, _attache_ c'est comme un _générique sous-jacent_, donc c'est vraiment surtout _une trombone_ pour moi mais je connais _attache-tout_ aussi semble-t-il, je dirais encore _une_. Dans mon souvenir _agrafe_ et _broche_ vont avec _agrafeuse_ et _brocheuse_ et ce sont pour moi des synonymes, le truc qui fait clac-clac. Une ou deux phrases choisies de ton propos et le BDLP permettent certainement de donner une réponse.

Comment: Je devais me sentir trop confiant en moi en écrivant ce premier commentaire. Je ne suis plus du tout certain de comprendre le sens de cette phrase du DHLF, donc je préfère m'abstenir de répondre.

Comment: @Anonymous C'pas grave, il y a du temps, un moment donné quelqu'un va s'essayer. Ça se voulait davantage comme un truc « français de nos régions » où on voit que tel mot est utilisé à tel endroit etc., le propos du DHLF est simplement une occasion de réfléchir là-dessus, ce qu'on a un peu fait, en plus je me suis rendu compte de mon emploi au féminin etc.